# Remove previous marker

Tags: android, google-maps, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-maps-markers

I am having a trouble. I am fetching my latitude and longitude in Realtime Firebase and created a marker but every time the latitude and longitude has an update it will create another marker.

How can I delete the previous marker? Here is my code:

```
passRef = new Firebase(Config.FIREBASE_URL_PASSENGER);
passRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot snapShot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            for (int cnt = 0; cnt <= dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount(); cnt++) {
                if (snapShot.child("latitude").exists() && snapShot.child("longitude").exists() && snapShot.child("destination").exists()) {

                    passUsername = snapShot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                    //getting the passenger's current location
                    locLatPass = Double.valueOf(snapShot.child("latitude").getValue().toString());
                    locLongPass = Double.valueOf(snapShot.child("longitude").getValue().toString());
                    latlngpass = new LatLng(locLatPass, locLongPass);

                    MarkerOptions passLocMarkerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                    passLocMarkerOptions.position(latlngpass);
                    passLocMarkerOptions.title(passUsername+ "'s Location");

                    passLocMarkerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE));
                    passLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(passLocMarkerOptions);
                } else {
                }
            }
            Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "Passenger Username" + passUsername + " latitude" + locLatPass + "Longitude" + locLongPass, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

This will clear all the existing markers drawn on map:

```
mMap.clear();
```

Comment: in every child there is a latitude and longitude. so every time there is an update even in just one child all my markers will updated you mean?

Comment: You can't remove a single marker from the map. You have to remove all pins and re-draw all with the updated one's.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the marker by calling its `remove()` method.

```
marker.remove();
```

**EDIT**

If each child's value will be changed, you should consider using `ChildEventListener`

Here is the solution to your problem, you have to create a HashMap to save the markers and then you can remove or just modify the previous marker.

```
Map<String, Marker> markers = new HashMap();

Database.waypoints().addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        passUsername = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
        //getting the passenger's current location
        locLatPass = Double.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child("latitude").getValue().toString());
        locLongPass = Double.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child("longitude").getValue().toString());
        latlngpass = new LatLng(locLatPass, locLongPass);

        MarkerOptions passLocMarkerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        passLocMarkerOptions.position(latlngpass);
        passLocMarkerOptions.title(passUsername+ "'s Location");

        passLocMarkerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE));
        Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(passLocMarkerOptions);
        markers.put(dataSnapshot.getKey(), marker);
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        passUsername = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
        //getting the passenger's current location
        locLatPass = Double.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child("latitude").getValue().toString());
        locLongPass = Double.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child("longitude").getValue().toString());
        latlngpass = new LatLng(locLatPass, locLongPass);

        MarkerOptions passLocMarkerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        passLocMarkerOptions.position(latlngpass);
        passLocMarkerOptions.title(passUsername+ "'s Location");

        if (markers.contains(dataSnapshot.getKey())) {
            markers.get(dataSnapshot.getKey()).remove();
            // you can also modify the marker instead of removing it and then add it again
        }
        passLocMarkerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE));
        Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(passLocMarkerOptions);
        markers.put(dataSnapshot.getKey(), marker);
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Comment: it still doesn't work :( it will remove all the markers leaving only one passLocationMarker.

Comment: can you explain why you do unnecessary loop after `for (DataSnapshot snapShot : dataSnapshot.getChildren())`? and please post the JSON of the database structure

Comment: @sweetzylpili your second loop is unnecessary, look at my updated answer

Comment: hello @wilik. I am having a trouble on this line: Database.waypoints().addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() { what do u mean about Database is it the firebase database that I wanna fetch?  this is what I did passRef = new Firebase(Config.FIREBASE_URL_PASSENGER); passRef.waypoints().addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() however waypoints() is a readline its says 
"cannot resolve method 'waypoints()'". Do I have to add another dependency on my grade app?

Comment: well that is just my example, just do this `passRef.addChildEventListener()` @sweetzylpili

Comment: please explain more clearly what didn't work, what have you tried, and what improvement have you done to the code @sweetzylpili

Comment: stated above are my codes. when my data in firebase updates it creat a new marker but it didn't remove the previous marker. still the same issue.